# Why has my cat started urinating outside of her litter box?

Tags: cats, behavior, toilet-training

Some information, we have 3 animals (all sterilized):

1. Mia, a 1 year old Female cat.
2. Bentley, a 2 year old Male cat.
3. Stella, a 1 ½ year old Female dog.

Both cats never go outside except for the balcony.

About 2 weeks ago, Mia began urinating on Stella's pillow every now and then (every few days). We washed it every time on sanitary cycle (a 3 hour cycle!!). After a few times, we decided to just trash the pillow thinking the washing machine couldn't get the smell off. But then today Mia urinated on our bed.

I'm wondering why she suddenly started doing this. We have 2 litter boxes and clean them every day. Bentley has never urinated anywhere else but in the litter boxes.

What can we do to solve this?

Comment: I think the first step is taking Mia to the vet to rule out any bladder or urinary tract problems.

Comment: Do these questions help: [How can I stop my adult cat from urinating in inappropriate places](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1009/how-can-stop-my-adult-cat-from-urinating-in-inappropriate-places), [How do I stop my cat from peeing on rugs and linens](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/3127/how-do-i-stop-my-cat-from-peeing-on-rugs-and-linens),

Comment: @Matt S. Thank you for the edit (English isn't my native language).

Comment: @Zaralynda I guess the first one helps a bit. We will try to buy new litter box (my girlfriend read somewhere that we should change them every year). If that does not help, we will go to the vet (he's on vacation for another week anyway...)

Comment: Okay I'll close this until you're able to try a new box and get to the vet. If neither of those things works, please come back and open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I had such problem. My cats started urinating on my bean bag. So whenever they woke up from sleep, I used to keep them in the liter. Also I kept the bean bag away from their reach for few days. So if possible change the bedding and make them urinate in the liter every now and then like a baby. This took me about 4 days to make them a habit.

Comment: She runs away when I put her in the litter. Will try with new ones as ours are 1+ year old (see my comment on question).