# Neutered male Maine Coon with me for 8 years has begun peeing on my bed

Tags: cats, toilet-training

There have been changes in our household in the last year, my granddaughter moved in with me September 2015, and I've rescued 2 kittens since August 2015.  Tiggy began this negative behavior about 4 months ago.  I scoop the litterbox often daily but this has not helped.  I've considered putting a litterbox in my bedroom but am not crazy about that idea though perhaps I should.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Breaking litterbox protocol is often an indication of illness.  Vet before anything else.

Comment: Do the following questions help: [How can I stop my adult cat from urinating in inappropriate places?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1009/how-can-stop-my-adult-cat-from-urinating-in-inappropriate-places) [How do I stop my cat from peeing on rugs and linens](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/3127/how-do-i-stop-my-cat-from-peeing-on-rugs-and-linens?rq=1)

Comment: If not, please edit your question to answer the following questions: 
Is your cat declawed? Have you tried different litters? Have you tried different types of boxes? Have you tried training him to pee pads? Have you taken him to the vet? With more details we can provide more tailored responses

Comment: While not exactly the same question, the very detailed answers there are, I think, a strong starting point.